# Query string compare fails in django views. Why?

Tags: python, django

I have a filter system that lets users filter out the games they've played by a few parameters that are stored as fields on the models. I'm passing in the filter as a query string from my template like this:

```
<li>
    <a href="{% url 'games_filter' %}?filter='my_active_games'&user={{user.email}}">My Active Games</a>
</li>
```

And in my views, I'm doing this:

```
def games_filter(request):
    objects_filter = str(request.GET.get('filter'))
    user = User.objects.get(email=request.GET.get('user'))

    if str(objects_filter) == 'my_active_games':
        raise Exception('Line 56')
        games = Game.objects.filter(Q(owner=user) & Q(status='New') or Q(status='Qualify'))

    elif str(objects_filter) == 'all_active_games':
        games = Game.objects.filter(Q(status="New") | Q(status="Qualify"))

    elif objects_filter == 'my_played':
        games = Game.objects.filter(Q(status="Played") & Q(owner=user))

    elif objects_filter == 'my_finished':
        games = Game.objects.filter(Q(status="Finished") & Q(owner=user))

    elif objects_filter == 'my_deleted':
        games = Game.objects.filter(Q(status="Deleted") & Q(owner=user))

    else:
        games = Game.objects.all()
```

But the function won't enter the first `if` condition, skips directly to the `else` part. I have tried:

1. Converting `objects_filter` to string by doing `str(objects_filter)`
2. Using `objects_filter.encode('utf8')`
3. Converting the `request.GET.get('filter')` to a string

Neither of these worked. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for single quotes in the URL. It should just be:

```
<li>
    <a href="{% url 'games_filter' %}?filter=my_active_games&user={{user.email}}">My Active Games</a>
</li>
```

If you added `print(objects_filter)` and didn't notice the problem before, you might have missed the quotes. In the future, try, `print(repr(my_string))` and it'll be much clearer that something is fishy. For example:

```
>>> my_string = "'hello'"
>>> print(my_string)
'hello'  # easy to miss
>>> print(repr(my_string))
"'hello'"  # two sets of quotes!
```

On another note, I'm guessing you added the `str(...)` calls after things wouldn't work. Fortunately, none of them are necessary.

Comment: Holy shitballs, that worked! I've been pulling my hair out for quite some time now! Thank you! I will accept your answer as soon as SO lets me!

Comment: No problem! I'm sure I've been in the same place before. The quotes are easy to glide your eyes over.

Comment: If your user is the logged in user, then just get it with `request.user` Also, in the first if block, how come you raised an exception, then proceed to issue a filter command?

Comment: I'm guessing @Di437 added the exception as a debugging measure. A fool proof way to check if your branch is being entered :)

Comment: @Parousia Yeah, sushain97 is right, that was a debug breakpoint.

Comment: I see. I usually use print statements.